# Install4j run service as local user instead domain user

Tags: windows-services, install4j

I have one task about get a file by external path (UNC).

I check this file on exists in Install Action with permissions of current domain user. After that I save this path for using in my application.

My application is a fat jar that runs as a service (Action 'Install a service').
After install process service try to run application but not successfully because windows-service run as local user instead domain user.
After that I try to stop service and manually run service with user domain credentials.

So... Can install4j run service with with domain rights without additional actions with credentials? I don't want to ask users for their login and password.

Answer (score 0):

The user accounts that are available out of the box are "Local system", "Local service" and "Network service", these can be selected in the "Account" property of the "Install a service" action.

If you select "Other", you have to fill in the "Account Name or SID" child property.

Comment: I tried to run windows service with local and network service and it doesn't work. Option with "Account Name or SID" it's not solution for us because user can change password and in service need to change password too. Could you suggest another variant?

Comment: No sorry, there is no other variant in install4j.